# Make lowercase URLs for minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

Say, I have the following minimal API:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Routing options
builder.Services
  .Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
  });

await using var app = builder.Build();

// API
app.MapGet("/api/customers/{id:int}", async (VRContext db, int id) =>
  await db.Customers.FindAsync(id) switch
  {
    { } customer => Results.Ok(customer),
    null => Results.NotFound(new { Requested_Id = id, Message = $"Customer not found." })
  });

//app.MapControllers();

await app.RunAsync();
```

When I pass non-existing `id`, I get the following JSON:

```json
{
  "requested_Id": 15,
  "message": "Customer not found."
}
```

The problem is that letter `I` in `requested_Id` is not lowercase, although I configured it in `Configure<RouteOptions>`. But when I start using fully-fledged controller, then I correctly get `requested_id`. How do I achieve the same with `MapGet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the default Json options (Note the `using` for the correct namespace)

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(
    options =>
    {
        options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new LowerCaseNamingPolicy();
    });

await using var app = builder.Build();

// API
app.MapGet("/api/customers/{id:int}", (int id) =>
        Results.NotFound(new { Requested_Id = id, Message = $"Customer not found." })
        );

await app.RunAsync();
```

```cs
internal class LowerCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name) => name.ToLowerInvariant();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below line fo code to convert all words in URL as lowercase

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```